# A box contains 10 balls numbered from 1 to 10

Tags: probability

An urn contains balls numbered $1, \ldots, 10$. Five balls are drawn without replacement. What is the probability that the second largest of the five numbers drawn will be 8?

I believe the number of possibilities are 10 * 9 * 8 * 7 * 6 but that is where I get stuck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are balls numbered? What do you mean by ball drawn will be 8?

Comment: Yes the balls are numbered 1 through 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break it down into two parts, the probability that 8 and 10 are chosen, and 9 isn't; and the probability that 8 and 9 are chosen and 10 isn't.  If 8, 9, and 10 are removed and we choose 3 from the remaining 7, we get

$$
{7 \choose 3}
$$

for the number of ways of 8 being the second largest with 10 as the largest, 
and also with 9 as the largest.  So the number of ways of choosing 5 balls with 8 as the second largest is

$$
2*{7 \choose 3}
$$

The number of ways of choosing 5 balls from 10 is

$$
{10 \choose 5}
$$

So the answer is

$$
\frac{2*{7 \choose 3}}{{10 \choose 5}}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Here's a hint: This would be equivalent to asking what the probability of (drawing a 10 OR a 9, but not both) AND (drawing an 8).

Try using those conditions to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

Another way of solving it is to use multivariate hypergeometric distribution:

Let us define A= 8, B = 9 or 10, C is three numbers from {1,2,..7}

Then $P(A = 1, B = 1, C = 3) = \dfrac{ {m1\choose a}{m2\choose b}{m3\choose c}}{{M\choose y}}$

In our problem, $m1 =1, m2 = 2, m3 = 7, a = 1, b = 1, c = 3, M = m1+m2+m3 = 10 ,  y = a+b+c = 5$

$$= \dfrac{ {1\choose 1}{2\choose 1}{7\choose 3}}{{10\choose 5}}$$

That will be solution.